# mysql regex to accept all international accent marks and no commas or exclamation

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying to create a function that accepts all characters, international accent marks. But any comma and exclamation mark should be excluded and the string rejected.

So far I have created a table with column that stores the values.
I need to move only those values forward that have no comma and exclamation marks.

The regex I am using is as below:

```
IF column_value not REGEXP concat('[',x'21','-',x'2C',x'2E','-',x'40',x'5B','-',x'60',x'7B','-',x'7E',x'A1','-',x'BF',']') then

 SET is_valid = 1;
```

This is not regexp format to reject rows that contain the characters I dont need. Everything else should be stored in the utf8_unicode_ci column i have created.

For now, all the values till HEX code (DF) is marked valid.
But, the remaining values are marked invalid. For example, `è` is marked invalid.
Can you please help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE table_name SET is_valid = 1 WHERE column_value NOT REGEXP '[,!]+';
```

or

```
UPDATE table_name SET is_valid = 1 WHERE column_value REGEXP '[^,!]+';
```

The short clarification about your last question about `è`:

I can see small latin letter E with combined grave accent. In unicode it is looks like `\u0065\u0300`, but in UTF-8 it is three bytes `\x65\xCC\x80`.
REGEX checks each byte separately. Let see your filter:

```
[
    \x21-\x2C //PASS
    \x2E-\x40 //PASS
    \x5B-\x60 //PASS
    \x7B-\x7E //PASS
    \xA1-\xBF //PASS
]
```

But if this is a latin small letter E with grave `\u00e8`, then UTF-8 is `\xC3\xA8`:

```
[
    \x21-\x2C //PASS
    \x2E-\x40 //PASS
    \x5B-\x60 //PASS
    \x7B-\x7E //PASS
    \xA1-\xBF // \xA8 IS FILTERED THERE
]
```

`è` and `è` looks the same and make all the mess. It is the reason to find the way simplify REGEX and avoid as much as it possible Unicode involvements in it.

Comment: Please consider adding more detail regarding the _why_ of your answer.

Comment: I believe this "moves only those values forward that have no comma and exclamation marks", as @Tammy mentioned above.

Comment: My problem is that i am validating first name of different countries. I can see now that many people have used numbers, ‡, ™(for company names). Since, they are not individuals, I am trying to filter them. That is the reason for using hex-codes. @Ruben, let me try to insert these characters in the not regexp and see if it does the job.

Comment: I believe it is hard to filter "everything else" but it is pretty straightforward to filter "exactly what you expect". Actually, (tm) in unicode is `U+2122`, because you working with UTF-8, you have it as three bytes `0xE2 0x84 0xA2`. The filter for (tm) should looks like `REGEXP [^\xE284A2]` or `NOT REGEXP [\xE284A2]`. The question is do you really ready to place in the square brackets all the Unicode table?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your guidance.

I have created a table with special characters and their hex-codes. I convert each string like hex('value of string'). Now, I use instr(hex('value of string'), @hex_value_from_table).

The @hex_value_from_table picks the value of each special character from the table and checks for the occurrence in the string. This way, if any character has to be removed, I dont change the regexp, instead i add/delete entries from the "value" table of special characters.

Query:

```
create table special_char_hex_codes
(
char_name varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Character to be rejected',
hex_value varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Character hexadecimal value'
);

set sql_safe_updates = 0;
delete from eligibility_file_reject_chars ;

insert into special_char_hex_codes select '€',hex('€')      ;

select instr(hex('Wilâmer'),trim(hex_value)) as str_exists
from
(
select char_name,hex_value from special_char_hex_codes 
) as test;
```